# Converting function signature from compiler language to c++

Tags: c++, linker, g++

Hey guys, I need to make a list of some functions that are listed in the linker output. The syntax i get is as follows:

```
int foo(int num,double dnum, Temp & temp) (in namespace "funcsns")
```

*Turns into:*

```
.text._ZN7funcsns3fooEidRNS_4TempE
```

(You might know it from the "undefined symbol" and some other linking errors that print functions names)

Now, i can write a script that somehow turns it into something readable but i wonder if there is a **smart** way of doing it.

Please share your ideas!

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a system using the GNU toolchain, the `c++filt` program does exactly what you're looking for.  It's part of the "binutils" package.  Dunno about other systems.

The ".text." isn't part of the mangled name.  Running `c++filt _ZN7funcsns3fooEidRNS_4TempE` yields `funcsns::foo(int, double, funcsns::Temp&)`.

Comment: Oh, wow; I wrote something a while ago that uses `abi::__cxa_demangle`; completely didn't realize there was already something for it

Answer (score 3):

This is called decoration or name mangling.  Here is some information on how it works for various compilers

http://www.kegel.com/mangle.html

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by other, `c++filt` is the way to go for the GNU toolchain.

This can also be done [programmaticaly](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) (even from a C program) : see `abi::__cxa_demangle` (which is actually what `c++filt` does).

Answer (score 1):

The undname utility provided with visual studio (At least VC2005 that I'm currently using) does the same as c++filt for microsoft visual c++